# aiohttp-form-based authentication

Tags: python, authentication, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I cannot find working code of `aiohttp` in combination with a login page. The goal is simple: form-based authentication with a username and password, which cookie I would like to use in subsequent aiohttp async fetch calls.

It seems that the whole Session concept changed in aiohttp between versions, so I'm curious how can I implement it in the most recent version. I'm not sure how to get the cookie once and then use it in the asynchronous matter.

I'd really like to see a **fully working example**, since unfortunately I wasn't able to get it working with the snippets I found everywhere.

I guess this might be the start, but I'm not sure and I certainly do not see how I can connect everything to it (do I also still need a `aiohttp.TCPConnector`?)
http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/client_reference.html#aiohttp.client.ClientSession

Example of my non-async version in Python 2 using mechanize (though I naturally use Python 3 for asyncio etc):

```
import mechanize
import urllib

class MyClass()
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {'username' : 'me', 'password' : 'pw'}
        self.login_url = 'http://example.com/login'
        self.login()

    def call(self, url):
        request2 = mechanize.Request(url)
        self.cookie_jar.add_cookie_header(request2)
        response2 = mechanize.urlopen(request2).read()
        return response2    

    def login(self):
        request = mechanize.Request(self.login_url)
        # 'username' and 'password' keys are actually the name of the <input>
        logInfo = urllib.urlencode({'username' : self.data['username'], 
                                    'password' : self.data['password']})
        response = mechanize.urlopen(request, data = logInfo)
        cookie_jar = mechanize.CookieJar()
        cookie_jar.extract_cookies(response, request)
        self.cookie_jar = cookie_jar

mc = MyClass()
mc.call('http://example.com/other_url')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just added example for basic auth on client side: [client_auth.py](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/examples/client_auth.py)

Is it enough for you?

P.S. Actually `ClientSession` is replacement for old-style `request`+`connector` concept. Session is more natural way to save session-related info. But old way is still working.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your reply! I'm still unable to do it; where do I actually give a url to login first? I updated my question to include the code before in Python 2.

Comment: Ok. Take a look on the snippet: https://gist.github.com/asvetlov/218a1d7d05a540d70a21

Comment: I cannot use print, for example, in my snippet mc.call returns the text. Your  `mc.call('http://example.com/other_url')` leaves a generator . When I try to print I get a `TypeError: A Future or coroutine is required`. It also complains about an unclosed response. Any idea?

Comment: Just to clarify: <generator object text>

Comment: Yes, both `call` and `login` are coroutines. You should apply `yield from` to them.

Comment: I think I got it working, but that the difference is that somehow mechanize is not bothered by the javascript on the page? I'm sure mechanize is not able to execute javascript, but still it "allows" it or something? Does `aiohttp` also have that option that you know?

Comment: I've used 3 websites to run the latest gist, and it doesn't work. It always tells me I'm not logged in (using your exact code, with the only difference username/password fields and values). In my defense, I've used urllib, requests, scrapy, mechanize and selenium, and this is the first time it's not working.

Comment: Perhaps you can find some kind of mistake with the code, I would really be grateful.

Comment: Well, that was embarrassing. It all had to do with the fact that I had to do a post for the login, very silly. Thanks anyway, it works great! We will use `aiohttp` for a customer!

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov: Is it possible to create `ClientSession` with `DigestAuth` ?